# При запуске деплоя через railway, код не пишет в текстовые файлы

Tags: python, файлы, github, асинхронность, запись

Всем привет! Запустил деплой через railway, но он не пишет данные в файл. Локально все работает. Причем через деплой он именно не пишет. С файла читает норм. Библиотека для записи используется aiofiles. Из за чего такое может быть? Доступы все railway даны в GitHub. Сам railway тянет репозиторий с GitHub. Ниже пример выполнения кода на запись.

```
async def read_file_async(response, answer):
  async with aiofiles.open("loggs.txt", mode='a', encoding="utf-8") as file:
    await file.write(f"Запрос:\n{response}\n\nОтвет:\n{answer}\n----------------\n\n\n")
```